# CORS error on react python application when trying to get body from API call

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors

I am not sure why I am getting a CORS error when I try to extract the body from a http request from the react app.
I dont get the error when I use postman to make the http error to the python server.

this is the python app.py file. I have labeled the line that is giving me an error when its not commented out.

I could not find any other stackoverflow issue like this.
there was a simimlar-ish question but it didnt help ([CORS error while making REST API calls from React JS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107412/cors-error-while-making-rest-api-calls-from-react-js-application))
chatgpt was not helping either

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

from routes.question_data_routes import question_data_bp
from routes.user_routes import user_bp
from middleware.auth import check_authorization
from services.mongodb import MongoDBConnector
from dotenv import load_dotenv

app = Flask(__name__)
load_dotenv()

CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000"], methods=["GET", "POST"], allow_headers=["Content-Type"])

mongo_connector = MongoDBConnector(app)

@app.route('/api/user/signup', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])  # Make sure OPTIONS method is handled
def signup():
    # Your signup logic
    data = request.get_json()  # THIS IS CAUSING THE ISSUE IF I DONT COMMENT IT OUT

    return jsonify({'message': 'Signup successful'}), 200
```

here is the error that I am getting::

```
auth:1 Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/user/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
auth.js:9     POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/user/signup net::ERR_FAILED
singUp @ auth.js:9
handleSubmit @ RegisterForm.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
auth.js:20 Error during signup: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at UserBackEndAPI.singUp (auth.js:9:1)
    at handleSubmit (RegisterForm.js:13:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
singUp @ auth.js:20
await in singUp (async)
handleSubmit @ RegisterForm.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Show 1 more frame
auth.js:9        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at UserBackEndAPI.singUp (auth.js:9:1)
    at handleSubmit (RegisterForm.js:13:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
```

not sure why I dont get the error if I comment out "data = request.get_json()"

here is the code from the react app that makes the api call::

```
  async singUp(name, email, password) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/api/user/signup`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, password }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during signup:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

it works perfect if I make the post request from postman

why am i getting that weird error when i try to extract the data from the body??

[image: postman1]

[image: postman2]

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code only in your machine then you can use the following extension which can prevent the CORS error

[CORS Access Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf).

This can help to test your react app during development.

Comment: it didnt work but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this ended up doing the trick::

```
def signup_controller():
    print('signup_controller()')
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        print('request.method == OPTIONS')
        # Handle CORS preflight request
        response = jsonify({'message': 'CORS preflight successful'})
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
        return response, 200
    print('AFTER CORS')
```

so just put that at the front.
not sure why it works but it works nice.